# staying in same page after submiting form button

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to stay on the same page after submitting a form button.
Depending on the button the user clicks, I want to display certain information on that same page the button was clicked.

For some reason it keeps redirecting me back to my "ask_login.php" page after I click on the button.
I've read around and some people recommend using AJAX or JQuery but  I don't really understand much about it. I'd be appreciated if I could get some help. Thanks.

**loggedin.php**

```
   <?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username && $password) {
        //info is provided
        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$username' AND password='$password'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);

            if($numrows != 0) {

                //something has been found
                $_SESSION['id'] = $username;



            } else {
                echo "Wrong username/password";
                echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
            }
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong username/password";
        echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
    }

    ?>


              <form method="POST" action="">
              <input type="submit" name="details" value="Details">
              </form>


                <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="optionB" value="option B">
                </form>

            <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="optionC" value="option C">
                </form>
```

Comment: you dont post username or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this following code is not correct...
     if($username && $password)

Try this

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form action="#">`. no action means 'submit to current url', the pound sign mean 'the current document' and should not navigate. though i'm not sure forms semantically allow this.
I would recommend posting the form data over ajax though. Its not hard to do, Jquery offers the most used ajax function and you basically loop though each input in a form and push the value into a uri-encoded string and post that via an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

i think it shout be

```
 <?php
if($_POST)
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password) {
    //info is provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);

        if($numrows != 0) {

            //something has been found
            $_SESSION['id'] = $username;



        } else {
            echo "Wrong username/password";
            echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
        }
}
else {
    echo "Wrong username/password";
    echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
}
}
?>


          <form method="POST" action="">
          <input type="submit" name="details" value="Details">
          </form>


            <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="optionB" value="option B">
            </form>

        <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="optionC" value="option C">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to process the form

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize(),function(e){alert(e);} );
```

test.php

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username && $password) {
        //info is provided
        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);

        if($numrows != 0) {

            //something has been found
            $_SESSION['id'] = $username;



        } else {
            echo "Wrong username/password";
            echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
        }
}
else {
    echo "Wrong username/password";
    echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are wrong');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
}

?>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

beware, no input validation!

read this page

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php